# Notation for Multiple summation

Tags: notation, summation

Is there an alternate way to represent the multiple summation given below?
$\displaystyle \Large \sum_{i_k=k}^{n} \space \sum_{i_{k-1}=k-1}^{i_k} \dots \sum_{i_2=2}^{i_3} \space \sum_{i_1=1}^{i_2}$
It guess it is wrong to write it as a product of summations like $\displaystyle \large \prod_{\Large j=k}^{1}\space \sum_{\Large i_j=j}^{\Large i_{j+1}}$.

What's a better, concise notation ?

**Update:**  Another way is $\displaystyle \quad \large \sum\limits_{\Large n \geq i_k \geq i_{k-1} \dots \geq i_2 \geq i_1 \geq 1}$.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Note that the update isn't correct, since it allows for $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ which your original notation doesn't allow for.

Comment: yea I missed one constraint. The answer by Goos seems to be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use
$$
\large \sum_{\substack{1 \le i_1 \le i_2 \le \cdots \le i_k \le n \\ i_j \ge j \;\; \forall j}}
$$

A summation in this form is understood to be taken over all ordered tuples $(i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_k)$ which satisfy the inequalities given.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation) for a list of various notational conventions.

Comment: @CalvinLin $i_j \ge j$ *is* in my condition.  Perhaps I misunderstand you (the OP copied down my sum incorrectly).

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't see that you had it. I just saw OP's version.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{l \le i_l \le i_{l+1}}_{ 1 \le l \le k}$... Is this type of notation accepatable? with $i_{k+1}=n$?